# Parsing text files to get some contains

Tags: php

I have some text files. for example: `file1.txt` and `file2.txt.`

The contain of `file1.txt` is `Walk word1 in the rain
Walking in the rain is one of the most beautiful word2 experiences.`

There are some conditions :

1. If there are `word1` AND `word2`, I wanna get the text between those 2 words as `$between` so I will get `in the rain
   Walking in the rain is one of the most beautiful`. And also I wanna get the text after `word2` as `$content` so I will get `experiences`
2. If there are only `word1` OR `word2` (eg = `Walk in the rain
   Walking in the rain is one of the most beautiful word1 experiences.`) Then `$between =''` and `$content` is all of texts-> `Walk in the rain
   Walking in the rain is one of the most beautiful word1 experiences.`
3. If `word2` in front of `word1` for example : `Walk in word2 the rain
   Walking in the rain is one of the most word1 beautiful word1 experiences.` then $between = ''`and`$content` is all of texts.

here's my code :

```
//to get and open the text files
$txt = glob($savePath.'*.txt');
foreach ($txt as $file => $files) {
    $handle = fopen($files, "r") or die ('can not open file');
    $ori_content = file_get_contents($files);

//count the words of text, to reach until the last word
$words = preg_split('/\s+/',$ori_content ,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$count = count ($words);

$word1 ='word1';
$word2 ='word2';
    if (stripos($ori_content, $word1) && stripos($ori_content, $word2)){
        $between  = substr($ori_content, stripos($ori_content, $word1)+ strlen($word1), stripos($ori_content, $word2) - stripos($ori_content, $word1)- strlen($word1));
        $content  = substr($ori_content, stripos($ori_content, $word2)+strlen($word2), stripos($ori_content, $ori_content[$count+1])  - stripos($ori_content,$word2));
    }
    else 
    $content = $ori_content;

$q0 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb VALUES('','$files','$content','$between')") or die(mysql_error());
```

but my code still cannot handle for :

1. the condition number 2(above), I get the result $between = experiences, it should be $between=''
2. the condition number 3(above). I get the result $etween = the rain
   Walking in the rain is one of the most word1 beautiful word1 experiences, it should be $between=''
3. If I get $between in file1.txt, but not in file2.txt, in table between in database, for data file2.txt it should be null in the column between. but it doesn't null, it filled by the between of other text files
4. I cannot reach the last word.

please help me.. thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing one statement:

```
...
}
else {
    $between = '';
    $content = $ori_content;
}
```

You're probably using this in a loop, so you get the values of the previous loop if you're not explicitly setting `$between` to an empty string :)

**Edit**

You also forgot to compare the positions:

```
if (stripos($ori_content, $word1) && stripos($ori_content, $word2)){
```

Should be:

```
$pos1 = stripos($ori_content, $word1);
$pos2 = stripos($ori_content, $word2);
if (false !== $pos1 && false !== $pos2 && $pos1 < $pos2) {
```

**Edit 2**

Another thing; your SQL is prone to injection and you can't properly use the `NULL` value this way. You could use this kind of construct, but it's more preferable to use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

```
$sql_between = is_null($between) ? 'NULL' : "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($between) . "'";
// apply the same treatment for `$files`, etc.
...
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb VALUES('', $sql_files, $sql_content, $sql_between)");
```

In this manner you can set `$between` to `null` and have it properly get sent to MySQL.

Comment: yes, you're right, silly me. thank you :) but I still have 3 others problems

Comment: @igo It should solve problem 1 and 2 actually (edited my answer). The other two problems are not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I've wrapped the parser logic into a function `parse_content`.

```
$txt = glob($savePath.'*.txt');
foreach ($txt as $file => $files) {
    $handle = fopen($files, "r") or die ('can not open file');
    $ori_content = file_get_contents($files);
    $word1 ='word1';
    $word2 ='word2';

    $result = parse_content($word1, $word2, $ori_content);
    extract($result);

    $q0 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb VALUES('','$files','$content','$between')") or die(mysql_error());

}


function parse_content($word1, $word2, $input) {
    $between = '';
    $content = '';

    $w1 = stripos($input, $word1);
    $w2 = stripos($input, $word2);

    if($w1 && $w2) {
        if($w2 < $w1) {
            // Case 3
            $content = $input;
        } else {
            // Case 1
            $reg_between = '/' . $word1 . '(.*?)' . $word2 . '/';
            $reg_content = '/' . $word2 . '(.*)$/';

            preg_match($reg_between, $input, $match);
            $between = trim($match[1]);
            preg_match($reg_content, $input, $match);
            $content = trim($match[1]);
        }
    } else if($w1 || $w2) {
        // Case 2
        $content = $input;
    } else {
        // Case 4
        $content = $input;
    }

    return compact('between', 'content');
}
```

Comment: oh, thank you so much. sorry I forgot to write the condition : if both words are not found then `$content = $input` :) I've tried your code, but it still give me blank result, except the last, in the condition both words are not found, it give me the correct result.

Comment: case for both not found is added

Comment: yes, I've also added it before and for that case gives correct result. but for the other cases it seems still does not work.